# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Game","params":{"roomId":"..."}} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a game in react-native (typescript) using firebase, but I encounter this error while adding a "Game" screen:

[image]

I have this code for my App.tsx :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Login from './app/screens/Authentication/Login';
import Register from './app/screens/Authentication/Register';
import Home from './app/screens/Home/Home';
import Game from './app/screens/Game/Game';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from './FirebaseConfig';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  ...

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              name='Login'
              component={Login}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name='Register'
              component={Register}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name='Game'
              component={Game}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here is the part of my types.tsx file :

```js
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Navigation
type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    Login: undefined;
    Register: undefined;
    Game: { roomId: string | null };
}

export type HomeNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;
export interface HomeProps {
    navigation: HomeNavigationProp;
}
export type RegisterNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Register'>;
export interface RegisterProps {
    navigation: RegisterNavigationProp;
}
export type LoginNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Login'>;
export interface LoginProps {
    navigation: LoginNavigationProp;
}
export type GameNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Game'>;
export interface GameProps {
    navigation: GameNavigationProp;
    route: {
        params: {
            roomId: string | null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this one raises an error while the 3 previous ones did not...

Full error :
[image]

Sorry for the long post, I can show more code if necessary but i have to admit i am truely clueless this time...
Thanks!

Comment: Check my repo for navigation example https://github.com/shivo-ham/EventManage/blob/main/src/navigation/navigatorStack.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move this part :

```js
<Stack.Screen
    name='Game'
    component={Game}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
/>
```

just next to Home instead of next to Login and Register screens.
It is because, the way it was, the user had to be undefined for the Game screen to be defined. (condition `user ?` in App.tsx)

Thanks to @DinhNguyen

Answer (score 1):

You should add `RootStackParamList` type:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can! Thanks for the answer

Comment: Okay so the error in the editor disappeared with this change so thank you, but i still have this error : 

`The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Game","params":{"roomId":"..."}} was not handled by any navigator.`

When i try to navigate to my screen... Any Idea ?

Comment: @Freddy Which screen you use `navigate` function?

Comment: In my Home screen. It calls this exported function :  
`export const joinRoom = async (auth: Auth, appId: string, nav: GameProps['navigation']) => { ... nav.navigate('Game', { roomId: room.id }); ... }`

with types :  

`export type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    ...
    Game: { roomId: string | null };
}

export type NavigationProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> = {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
}

export type HomeProps = NavigationProps<'Home'>;
...
export type GameProps = NavigationProps<'Game'>;`

Comment: Because you check `user` in `Stack.Navigator`, Home `Stack.Screen` and Game `Stack.Screen` cannot exists at the same time, so if you are in `Home`, you cannot navigate to `Game`

Comment: Okay this makes sense, but I should have the same problem if I wanted to go to Login or Register from Home right ? But i CAN do this and it works very well... I might be missing something maybe

Comment: You only can go to Login or Register from Home by change `user`'s value. You should check your code again